# Basic HTTP auth in actix-web

Tags: http, rust, basic-authentication, http-authentication, actix-web

I'm really new to web development and I'm stuck trying to implement a simple HTTP auth in a project using [`actix-web`](https://actix.rs/). My needs are following:

- I don't want/need any databases for the auth. It's enough for me to access the username and pass from enviroment variables, which will be provided when the docker container is run.
- I just need authentication for the `/api/*` routes. All the other routes should stay public.
- Ideally, it should be done using basic HTTP auth and stored in session.

I tried to use the [`actix_web_httpauth`](https://docs.rs/actix-web-httpauth/latest/actix_web_httpauth/) crate but I couldn't find enough documentation to implement in for my usecase.

Again, this is probably an easy thing to do, but I'm not at all familiar with web development. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [this](https://crates.io/crates/actix-jwt-auth-middleware) crate. It is quite simple but also offers solutions for more complicated things.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the [`actix-session`](https://crates.io/crates/actix-session) to build a custom solution.